# Python for loop to select elements in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below lists

```
list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Code:

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
...     a = list1[i]
...     b = list1[i + 1]
...     print a, b
...
```

output:

```
a1 a2
a2 a3
a3 a4
```

Expected output:

```
a1 a2
a3 a4
a5 a6
```

Please help

Comment: @Austin, list1 is not constant values, it may vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix:

```
for i, x in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    a = list1[i*2]
    b = list1[i*2 + 1]
    print a, b
```

Output:

```
a1 a2
a3 a4
a5 a6
```

Comment: I don't know the use of _list2_ here, if you just want to select elements in list with a range, `for slice in map(lambda i:l[2*i:2*(i+1)], range(3)): print(slice)`